# My lempel zip implementation makes encoding longer

Tags: python, compression

I can't work out why my implementation is creating a longer string than the input.

It is implemented according to the description in this document and only this description.

It is simply designed to act on binary strings only. If anyone can shed some light on why this creates a longer string than it started with I'd be very greatful!

Main Encoding

```
def LZ_encode(uncompressed):
    m=uncompressed
    dictionary=dict_gen(m)
    list=[int(bin(i)[2:]) for i in range(1,len(dictionary))]
    pointer_bit=[]
    for k in list:
        pointer_bit=pointer_bit+[(str(chopped_lookup(k,dictionary)),dictionary[k][-1])]
    new_pointer_bit=pointer_length_correct(pointer_bit)
    list_output=[i for sub in new_pointer_bit for i in sub]
    if list_output[-1]=='$':
        output=''.join(list_output[:-1])
    else:
        output=''.join(list_output)
    return output
```

Component Functions

```
def dict_gen(m): # Generates Dictionary
    dictionary={0:""}
    j=1
    w=""
    iterator=0
    l=len(m)
    for c in m:
        iterator+=1
        wc= str(str(w) + str(c))
        if wc in dictionary.values():
            w=wc
            if iterator==l:
                dictionary.update({int(bin(j)[2:]): wc+'$'})
        else:
            dictionary.update({int(bin(j)[2:]): wc})
            w=""
            j+=1
    return dictionary

def chopped_lookup(k,dictionary): # Returns entry number of shortened source string
    cut_source_string=dictionary[k][:-1]
    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        if value == cut_source_string:
            return key
def pointer_length_correct(lst): # Takes the (pointer,bit) list and corrects the lenth of the pointer
    new_pointer_bit=[]
    for pair in lst:
        n=lst.index(pair)
        if len(str(pair[0]))>ceil(log(n+1,2)):
            while len(str(pair[0]))!=ceil(log(n+1,2)):
                pair = (str(pair[0])[1:],pair[1])
        if len(str(pair[0]))<ceil(log(n+1,2)):
            while len(str(pair[0]))!=ceil(log(n+1,2)):
                pair = (str('0'+str(pair[0])),pair[1])
        new_pointer_bit=new_pointer_bit+[pair]
    return new_pointer_bit
```

Comment: You can write code inside formatted code blocks, e.g. with back-ticks  `this is code`

Comment: Your code is very dirty. By the way, what happens in `pointer_length_correct` when `len(str(pair[0]))==ceil(log(n+1,2))`? And please never assign anything to `list`.

Comment: What input values have you tested with? This algorithm can create an output string that is longer than the input string; if your concern is finding out if your code works I would suggest writing the corresponding decompression function so that you can test by running a piece of data through both and making sure it comes out the way it went in.

Comment: @DYZ I know! I've very little programming experience. In `pointer_length_correct`, if the equality holds nothing needs to be done since the pointer is already of the correct length. @Irisshpunk I've tested with a whole range of binary strings up to those with 10,000 digits! I know that for short input strings it can return a larger string but it should start to compress quite quickly with increased input size. Also I have written a decode function which always decodes correctly.